# Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'TypedAction. How i can access the action.payload from a ngrx effect?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm learning how to use ngrx effects in Angular. I'm following the ngrx documentation and i try to make my first effect:

In my component i make a `dispatch()` to load a list of users:

```
public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.store.dispatch({ type: '[User Page] Load Users' });
}
```

I create this effect to listen my actions and make the call from my api:

```
loadUsers$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('[User Page] Load Users'),
    mergeMap(() =>
      this.usuarioService.read().pipe(
        map((users) => ({
          type: '[Users API] Users Loaded Success',
          payload: users
        })),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
      )
    )
  )
);
```

This is my reducer:

```
export const initialState = {
  users: []
};

const _userReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(setUserList, (state, action) => ({ ...state, users: action.payload }))
);
```

This is my `setUserList` action:

```
export const setUserList = createAction('[Users API] Users Loaded Success');
```

Everything is working but i'm receiving an warning in my vscode when i try to access the action.payload:

> Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'TypedAction<"[Users API]
>   Users Loaded Success"> & { type: "[Users API] Users Loaded Success";
>   }'.ts(2339)

How i can fix this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `users` as a property of your action with the type User[], so:

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';

export interface User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export const setUserList = createAction('[Users API] Users Loaded Success', props<{ users: User[] }>());
```

More about this [here](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/actions#writing-actions).

Then in your effect, I believe you can just do:

```
map((users) => ({
    type: '[Users API] Users Loaded Success',
    users
})),
```

Comment: This works better than a IActionWithPayload with type: any

Comment: i can use the created action setUserList instead the object ({type: '[Users API]...'}) or i have to pass the type and the object users in my effect?

Answer (score 0):

I fix this warning creating a interface that have the payload property:

```
import { Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';

export interface IActionWithPayload extends Actions {
  type: string;
  payload?: any;
}
```

So i typed my action with this interface and the error is gone:

```
const _userReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(setUserList, (state, action: IActionWithPayload) => ({
    ...state,
    users: action.payload
  }))
);
```

Comment: Ideally you want to avoid using `any` because you're missing out on the benefits of typescript. As I'm sure you've guessed You've got a typescript error somewhere - if you want to set up a stackblitz I'll take a look?

Comment: you think is more appropriate create a interface for each different payload that i can have be?

Comment: What you've done is correct, in that you have an interface called `user` which defines the type of data you expect to get back from `this.usuarioService.read()`. It shouldn't be necessary to set up any other interfaces.